# Cannot convert "System.Collections.Hashtable" to type "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to create Dictionary in Powershell and pass it to C# function

```
$params= @{"abc"="123","xyz"=$False};
```

C# method accepts `Dictionary<string,object>` as arguments.

When I try call `MyFunc($params)` from PowerShell, I am getting below error

> Cannot convert argument "arguments", with value:
>   "System.Collections.Hashtable", for "MyFunc" to type
>   "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[System.String,System.String]":
>   "Cannot create object of type
>   "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[System.String,System.String]"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's what it says, you've created `HashTable` in PowerShell, but trying to use it as a `Dictionary` in C#. You have to change everything to be either one or another. Just in case, here's the dictionary declaration for Powershell:

```
$params = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[String,object]'
$params.Add("abc","123")
```

Or you can change your C# method to accept `HashTable`

Comment: C# accepts `string,object` type.
I did try this 
`$params= New-Object System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[String,Object]
$params.Add("abc","123");`


But I was getting this error
`Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ComObject'. Specified method is not supported.`

Comment: Works just fine for me (provided you get quotes right). What is your powershell version?

Comment: it's weird. Without `quote '` its' not working. However I got used to create object without quotes for long time `New-Object com.abc.test` works fine in other cases